# Dynamic Lists in R

Tags: r, list

Suppose I have the next list

```
list<-list(c(5,4,3,2),
       c(4.5,3.5,2.5,1.5), 
       c(4,3,2,1), 
       c(3.5,2,1.5,0.7))
```

and what I want to achieve is the next order

```
[[1]]
[1] 5 4.5 4 3.5

[[2]]
[1] 4 3.5 3 2

[[3]]
[1] 3 2.5 2 1.5

[[4]]
[1] 2 1.5 1 0.7
```

I did something like this with poor results

```
nueva_lista=list()
for (i in 1:4){
  for (j in 1:4){
  nueva_lista[[i]][j]<=list[[j]][i]
  }
}
```

Where is the mistake? thanks!

Comment: In your code what is `b_ac`

Comment: Sorry, b_ac is 'list'. I corrected the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
list %>% 
     transpose() %>% 
     map(unlist)
#[[1]]
#[1] 5.0 4.5 4.0 3.5

#[[2]]
#[1] 4.0 3.5 3.0 2.0

#[[3]]
#[1] 3.0 2.5 2.0 1.5

#[[4]]
#[1] 2.0 1.5 1.0 0.7
```